# Turn editing On button is showing in course page to authenticated users

Tags: moodle

Turn editing On button is showing in course page to authenticated users in Moodle.
I have tried editing authenticated users permissions but it is still there.
Seems like some permissions are overriding but i can't set it to default.

In the reports setting, capability block is showing following line:
moodle/course:update: Update course settings

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling from 2 days with this issue, finally find solution. This might help someone in future.

Actually the scenario is that Every guest and loged in user is having same rights as "Authenticated user" in moodle. (version 3.0)

issue was that authenticated user is having right to edit course. There was no permission assigned to authenticated user except following:

block/community:myaddinstance
block/course_list:myaddinstance
block/course_overview:myaddinstance
Add a new random glossary entry block to Dashboard
block/html:myaddinstance
block/navigation:myaddinstance
block/news_items:myaddinstance
moodle/portfolio:export
moodle/user:manageownfiles
report/courseoverview:view
moodle/badges:earnbadge
moodle/calendar:manageownentries
moodle/comment:post
moodle/comment:view
moodle/course:sectionvisibility
moodle/course:viewhiddensections
moodle/rating:viewall
moodle/rating:viewany
block/online_users:viewlist
block/site_main_menu:addinstance
moodle/block:view
mod/folder:view
mod/imscp:view
mod/page:view

I turned the following permission to Prohibit and now turn editing on button is not showing to Authenticated Users. Still don't know which of the following worked for this issue. but any one struggling with this issue can overview complete list of permissions from this post.

moodle/comment:post
moodle/comment:view
moodle/course:sectionvisibility
moodle/course:viewhiddensections
moodle/rating:viewall
moodle/rating:viewany
block/online_users:viewlist
block/site_main_menu:addinstance